# ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections mysql.pool.query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have create an api with Node.js and mysql. I use this api from android but not an issue in that part.

After a lot of calls I am getting the "classic" error `ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections` but I am using only calls with pool `res.locals.pool.query` and as far as I know the call `pool.query` closes automatically the connection to server.

So I added debug info to check the values of connections and etc. while looking the code I was getting `_allConnections : {1}` because in my code I don't use anything other to have multiple opened connections, but after some hours the `_allConnections` become `0` and I am getting the error, any clue??

*I am not a JS developer so I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but it looks like ok to me.*

**db.controller.js**

```
var dbConfig = {
    host: '*.*.*.*',
    user: '********',
    password: '*********',
    database: '*********',
    acquireTimeout: 1000000,
    queueLimit : 0,
    connectionLimit : 5
}

module.exports.initDB = function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals = { 
        pool: mysql.createPool(dbConfig)
    };
    next();
};
```

**apiCall**

```
res.locals.pool.query("QUERY HERE", req.query.param_here, function (error, results) {
    console.debug("\x1b[33m%s################### start connection info ###################");
    console.debug("connectionLimit : {" + res.locals.pool.config.connectionLimit + "} ");
    console.debug("_freeConnections : {" + res.locals.pool._freeConnections.length + "} ");
    console.debug("_allConnections : {" + res.locals.pool._allConnections.length + "} ");
    console.debug("_acquiringConnections : {" + res.locals.pool._acquiringConnections.length + "} ");
    console.debug("################### end connection info ###################\x1b[0m");
    global.handleResponse("call", res, error, results)
});
```

Comment: Are you hosting this on a function as a service or something like that? Pool connection manages to open and release connections, but sometimes it may keep a connection opened for a potential next time. This is useful on a classic server but a bad idea when is executed a intermittently

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this api either, but the acquireTimeout, connectionLimit, and queueLimit look suspicious. Other examples I see let the engine decide of these values for itself, have you tried without them? Specifically, it seems to me that 5 connections is a bit low, and can be filled out quickly, especially if each of them waits for the whole value of the acquireTimeout before disconnecting.

Comment: @Cinn I am using it as an express app just to host the api.
I don't get why I don't have _allConnections as 2, 3, 4 or 5 but I have the error `ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier 5 it was for debug purposes to get the error faster, but I didn't see on logs more than 1 simultaneously connections. queueLimit 0 is for infinity